# Divs not stacking vertically when shrinking browser using flexbox

Tags: html, css, flexbox

For whatever reason I can't figure this simple thing out. I've 3 divs that I want to stack when shrinking the browser using flexbox, however I must be missing something. Any insight would be appreciated. I merely want to just make these responsive & have actually done this before but maybe I am going crazy :).

```css
.container {
  position: relative;
  display: grid;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  flex-direction: row;
}

.item {
  margin: 3px;
  padding: 10px 0 0 10px;
  display: grid;
  flex-direction: row;
}

.item img {
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

.description {
  font-family: 'Nunito', sans-serif;
  color: #000;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="item">
    <a href="#">
      <img width="400" height="400" src="https://placekitten.com/400/400" />
    </a>
    <div class="info">
      <a href="#">Cheetah</a>
    </div>
    <div class="description">
      The cheetah is an atypical member of the cat family that is unique in its speed, while lacking climbing abilities.
    </div>
    <div>
      <a href="#">Learn more</a>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="item">
    <a href="#">
      <img width="400" height="400" src="https://placekitten.com/400/400" />
    </a>
    <div class="info">
      <a href="#">Cheetah</a>
    </div>
    <div class="description">
      The cheetah is an atypical member of the cat family that is unique in its speed, while lacking climbing abilities.
    </div>
    <div>
      <a href="#">Learn more</a>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="item">
    <a href="#">
      <img width="400" height="400" src="https://placekitten.com/400/400" />
    </a>
    <div class="type">
      <a href="#">Cheetah</a>
    </div>
    <div class="description">
      The cheetah is an atypical member of the cat family that is unique in its speed, while lacking climbing abilities.
    </div>
    <div>
      <a href="#">Learn more</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: use a media query with according settings

Comment: Ideally you should use `display: grid;`, with auto-columns not `display: flex;`, that way you don't need to manually define `@media`-queries and it will automatically adapt to _any_ browser window size.

Comment: @Dai thanks but now they're just stacking vertically all around

Comment: @erics15 Please update your post with a Snippet (the button is on the toolbar) with your **latest/current** HTML+CSS.

Comment: @Dai updated just now

Comment: You're using `display: grid;` on the wrong elements...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, 150px);` to have a CSS grid layout that automatically adapts to the viewport size without needing to hardcode `@media` rules.

For example:

```css
.container {
  
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, 150px);
  gap: 1em;
}

.item {
  margin: 3px;
  padding: 10px 0 0 10px;
  
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.item img {
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

.description {
  font-family: 'Nunito', sans-serif;
  color: #000;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="item">
    <a href="#">
      <img width="400" height="400" src="https://placekitten.com/400/400" />
    </a>
    <div class="info">
      <a href="#">Cheetah</a>
    </div>
    <div class="description">
      The cheetah is an atypical member of the cat family that is unique in its speed, while lacking climbing abilities.
    </div>
    <div>
      <a href="#">Learn more</a>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="item">
    <a href="#">
      <img width="400" height="400" src="https://placekitten.com/400/400" />
    </a>
    <div class="info">
      <a href="#">Cheetah</a>
    </div>
    <div class="description">
      The cheetah is an atypical member of the cat family that is unique in its speed, while lacking climbing abilities.
    </div>
    <div>
      <a href="#">Learn more</a>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="item">
    <a href="#">
      <img width="400" height="400" src="https://placekitten.com/400/400" />
    </a>
    <div class="type">
      <a href="#">Cheetah</a>
    </div>
    <div class="description">
      The cheetah is an atypical member of the cat family that is unique in its speed, while lacking climbing abilities.
    </div>
    <div>
      <a href="#">Learn more</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks so much! I had this type of code in another project but for some reason I just couldn't figure it out :)